# How to print firnedly urls in admin side OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

As you know in Opencart -> Catalog when you generete link like this

```
$this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
```

become

```
domain/category/product name
```

i tried to use same in Admin side to see what combination of category/product name exist atm but is not working same as Catalog side

Any ideas how can i print in Admin side rewrited urls same as Catalog side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File in "system/library/url.php" this path is rewriting url in to seo url.
In the seo_url table, for category we use "product/category" in the user end. but for admin end we need to use "catalog/category".

We can try by copying .htaccess to admin folder and also by trying to use "catalog/category" in seo table.